# xsd generator to C#/protobuf

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

i'm working on an app that is serializing and deserializing messages across the wire. But i'm having an issue with a C# class generated from an xsd schema using xsd.

I was able to successfully test the protobuf library with my own test class. installing the lib and decorating my class with the necessary protobuf attributes including integer order.

i understand from the documentation that protobuf honors existing serialization attributes like xmltype, datacontract etc. When i run the xsdgen tool my classes are decorated with those attributes but the serialization process is not happening.

i tried creating a partial class but it was still quite manual if i have many classes and the classes are constantly changing.

this is my xsd command [xsd TopClass.xsd /c /eld /edb /n:MyNamespace /order]

Can someone recommend a solution?

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("safHeartBeat", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class SaFHeartBeat {

    private System.DateTime timestampField;
    private string cacheNameField;
    private string hostnameField;
    private System.DateTime processStartTimeField;
    private SafStatusEnum statusField;
    private object datatypeField;
    private int itemCountField;
    private System.DateTime lastUpdateTimeField;
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public System.DateTime timestamp {
        get {
            return this.timestampField;
        }
        set {
            this.timestampField = value;
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string cacheName {
        get {
            return this.cacheNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.cacheNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public string hostname {
        get {
            return this.hostnameField;
        }
        set {
            this.hostnameField = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you define "not happening"? What *does* happen?

Comment: serialization to stream yields no result. string result is empty. what it does is compile and not give any runtime errors.

Comment: the Order=1 is problematic. Vexingly, there is inbuilt support for an automatic offset vs DataMemberAttribute, but not XmlElementAttribute. I will have to check (not at a PC right now) to say more, though.

Comment: what if i took these classes and used a WCF exporter/converter? so basically mirror the complete WCF data structure. would that work? or we still need the order elements etc. thanks again for the help

Comment: frankly the `partial class` approach would be simpler...

Answer (score 0):

protobuf-net can *try* to use attributes from other libraries, but only when they supply enough information. In particular, protocol buffers requires a positive integer identifier per member (which it can try to get from `Order`), but: `[XmlAttribute]` *has* no `Order`, and xsd annoyingly starts the `Order` from `0`, which can't be used by protocol buffers (it is not a valid field identifier).

Ultimately, this may not be a good fit for in-progress/changing definitions from xsd; I would be tempted to say "write a separate DTO later for protobuf". However, another option is to generate a second `partial` class file, and decorate *that*, for example:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoPartialMember(1, "Id"), ProtoPartialMember(2, "Name")]
    partial class SomeType {}

    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoPartialMember(1, "Id"), ProtoPartialMember(2, "Date")]
    [ProtoPartialMember(3, "Value"), ProtoPartialMember(4, "Origin")]
    partial class SomeOtherType {}
}
```

This will still need to be maintained to include the members you need to serialize, though.

Comment: Thanks Mark. i attached a snippet of what the xsd output was for a class. would this not work? order looks correct.